# Error or it does not execute BWWalkthrough

Tags: swift, bwwalkthrough

So I have followed your tutorial step by step. Still having issues...

I have installed it first with CocoaPods and seems that others are having the same issue.

If I name the custom class module (top right on the identity inspector) BWWalkthrough it will crash with the following line

```
 let walkthrough = stb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("onboardingZero") as! BWWalkthroughViewController
```

Could not cast value of type 'BWWalkthrough.BWWalkthroughViewController' (0x1054e6b50) to 'NameOfMyProject.BWWalkthroughViewController'

If I change the custom class module to NameOfMyProject (or leave it blank) it does not crash and the initial View Controller loads fine, when I tap the first button it simply does not load step0, the code executes fine, but nothing happens and I never get to see the first BWWalkthroughViewController.

I have tried with both cocoaPods and by copying the files. Spent a good two hours looking at this and got nowhere. Please help!!!!!

Comment: same here, I suspect it is a bug but I can't pinpoint where it happens. Weirdly enough, the demo project works fine but implementing it by myself I get the same result as you

Comment: You should try to import BWWalkthrough manually instead of using CocoaPods (just 2 files to drag and drop into your project).